# Djano - автозаполнение поля

Tags: django

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста реализовать вот что.
Django.
Есть модель:

```
class Links(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(...)
    title =  models.CharField(....)
```

Есть функция: `get_title(url),` которая возвращает title страницы.

Как сделать так, чтобы после того, как пользователь ввел url в форме, поле title заполнилось автоматически и приняло значение `title = get_title(url).`

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вот наглядный пример, как это делается:
[image: Пример]

Comment: картинки — это замечательно, но текст был бы ещё лучше: его поисковики проиндексируют, и ответ может помочь большему количеству людей.

Comment: Павел, извините, но я не поняла ответа, опыта у меня совсем ничего. Мне кажется, это обычная схема заполнения формы. А вопрос именно в автозаполении поля - как должна выглядеть вьюшка. Пользователь заполнил поле url в форме. Получается, что дальше нужен submit. Но форма на этом закончила свою жизнь, запись добавлена.  А дальше  то, что не могу сделать - нужно как-то автозаполнить поле title для этой записи (редактировать по id?) и показать пользователю форму с автозаполненным полем. Подскажите пожалуйста идею хотя бы в общих чертах.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"meta_title": ("name",)}
class ArticlesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}

admin.site.register(Articles, ArticlesAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

это у меня в админке.. с учетом того что в моей модели slug это имя статьи или товара, написанное латиницей, пробелы заменены дефисами, с помощью этого можно генерить ЧПУ типа : mysite.com/product/kvadrokoptery.html

Comment: Андрей, спасибо. А что у вас во вьюшке, форме и модели (model.Model)? Интересует  ввод пользователем, не только админка